# Convert Ruby DateTime string to Milliseconds

Tags: ruby, datetime

I am looking into how to convert the following Ruby DateTime into milliseconds in order to use [Angular Timer](http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/) which looks to be using milliseconds as the value to be passed for `countdown` in the "**Countdown time display according to specified max-time-unit**" example.

`"2016-02-03T16:38:00.000-05:00"`

I have tried using `to_f` like below, but it is not right:

```
t = event.actual_end_time
#=> "2016-02-03T16:38:00.000-05:00"
t.to_f * 1000
#=> 2016000.0
```

Answer (score 5):

```
require 'date'
puts DateTime.now.strftime('%Q')
```